# Peak Detection Using the Lomb-Scargle Method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to get a Python code working that finds peaks in data using the Lomb-Scargle method.

http://www.astropython.org/snippets/fast-lomb-scargle-algorithm32/

Using this method as below,

```
import lomb
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)
fx,fy, nout, jmax, prob = lomb.fasper(x,y, 6., 6.)
print jmax
```

works fine, without problems. It prints 8. However on another piece of data  (data dump below),

```
df = pd.read_csv('extinct.csv',header=None)
Y = pd.rolling_mean(df[0],window=5)
fx,fy, nout, jmax, prob = lomb.fasper(np.array(Y.index),np.array(Y),6.,6.)
print jmax
```

displays only 0. I tried passing different ofac,hifac values, none gives me sensible values.

Main function

```
"""
from numpy import *
from numpy.fft import *

def __spread__(y, yy, n, x, m):
  """
  Given an array yy(0:n-1), extirpolate (spread) a value y into
  m actual array elements that best approximate the "fictional"
  (i.e., possible noninteger) array element number x. The weights
  used are coefficients of the Lagrange interpolating polynomial
  Arguments:
    y : 
    yy : 
    n : 
    x : 
    m : 
  Returns:

  """
  nfac=[0,1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880]
  if m > 10. :
    print 'factorial table too small in spread'
    return

  ix=long(x)
  if x == float(ix): 
    yy[ix]=yy[ix]+y
  else:
    ilo = long(x-0.5*float(m)+1.0)
    ilo = min( max( ilo , 1 ), n-m+1 ) 
    ihi = ilo+m-1
    nden = nfac[m]
    fac=x-ilo
    for j in range(ilo+1,ihi+1): fac = fac*(x-j)
    yy[ihi] = yy[ihi] + y*fac/(nden*(x-ihi))
    for j in range(ihi-1,ilo-1,-1):
      nden=(nden/(j+1-ilo))*(j-ihi)
      yy[j] = yy[j] + y*fac/(nden*(x-j))

def fasper(x,y,ofac,hifac, MACC=4):
  """ function fasper
    Given abscissas x (which need not be equally spaced) and ordinates
    y, and given a desired oversampling factor ofac (a typical value
    being 4 or larger). this routine creates an array wk1 with a
    sequence of nout increasing frequencies (not angular frequencies)
    up to hifac times the "average" Nyquist frequency, and creates
    an array wk2 with the values of the Lomb normalized periodogram at
    those frequencies. The arrays x and y are not altered. This
    routine also returns jmax such that wk2(jmax) is the maximum
    element in wk2, and prob, an estimate of the significance of that
    maximum against the hypothesis of random noise. A small value of prob
    indicates that a significant periodic signal is present.

  Reference: 
    Press, W. H. &amp; Rybicki, G. B. 1989
    ApJ vol. 338, p. 277-280.
    Fast algorithm for spectral analysis of unevenly sampled data
    (1989ApJ...338..277P)

  Arguments:
      X   : Abscissas array, (e.g. an array of times).
      Y   : Ordinates array, (e.g. corresponding counts).
      Ofac : Oversampling factor.
      Hifac : Hifac * "average" Nyquist frequency = highest frequency
           for which values of the Lomb normalized periodogram will
           be calculated.

   Returns:
      Wk1 : An array of Lomb periodogram frequencies.
      Wk2 : An array of corresponding values of the Lomb periodogram.
      Nout : Wk1 &amp; Wk2 dimensions (number of calculated frequencies)
      Jmax : The array index corresponding to the MAX( Wk2 ).
      Prob : False Alarm Probability of the largest Periodogram value
      MACC : Number of interpolation points per 1/4 cycle
            of highest frequency

  History:
    02/23/2009, v1.0, MF
      Translation of IDL code (orig. Numerical recipies)
  """
  #Check dimensions of input arrays
  n = long(len(x))
  if n != len(y):
    print 'Incompatible arrays.'
    return

  nout  = 0.5*ofac*hifac*n
  nfreqt = long(ofac*hifac*n*MACC)   #Size the FFT as next power
  nfreq = 64L             # of 2 above nfreqt.

  while nfreq < nfreqt: 
    nfreq = 2*nfreq

  ndim = long(2*nfreq)

  #Compute the mean, variance
  ave = y.mean()
  ##sample variance because the divisor is N-1
  var = ((y-y.mean())**2).sum()/(len(y)-1) 
  # and range of the data.
  xmin = x.min()
  xmax = x.max()
  xdif = xmax-xmin

  #extirpolate the data into the workspaces
  wk1 = zeros(ndim, dtype='complex')
  wk2 = zeros(ndim, dtype='complex')

  fac  = ndim/(xdif*ofac)
  fndim = ndim
  ck  = ((x-xmin)*fac) % fndim
  ckk  = (2.0*ck) % fndim

  for j in range(0L, n):
    __spread__(y[j]-ave,wk1,ndim,ck[j],MACC)
    __spread__(1.0,wk2,ndim,ckk[j],MACC)

  #Take the Fast Fourier Transforms
  wk1 = ifft( wk1 )*len(wk1)
  wk2 = ifft( wk2 )*len(wk1)

  wk1 = wk1[1:nout+1]
  wk2 = wk2[1:nout+1]
  rwk1 = wk1.real
  iwk1 = wk1.imag
  rwk2 = wk2.real
  iwk2 = wk2.imag

  df  = 1.0/(xdif*ofac)

  #Compute the Lomb value for each frequency
  hypo2 = 2.0 * abs( wk2 )
  hc2wt = rwk2/hypo2
  hs2wt = iwk2/hypo2

  cwt  = sqrt(0.5+hc2wt)
  swt  = sign(hs2wt)*(sqrt(0.5-hc2wt))
  den  = 0.5*n+hc2wt*rwk2+hs2wt*iwk2
  cterm = (cwt*rwk1+swt*iwk1)**2./den
  sterm = (cwt*iwk1-swt*rwk1)**2./(n-den)

  wk1 = df*(arange(nout, dtype='float')+1.)
  wk2 = (cterm+sterm)/(2.0*var)
  pmax = wk2.max()
  jmax = wk2.argmax()


  #Significance estimation
  #expy = exp(-wk2)          
  #effm = 2.0*(nout)/ofac       
  #sig = effm*expy
  #ind = (sig > 0.01).nonzero()
  #sig[ind] = 1.0-(1.0-expy[ind])**effm

  #Estimate significance of largest peak value
  expy = exp(-pmax)          
  effm = 2.0*(nout)/ofac       
  prob = effm*expy

  if prob > 0.01: 
    prob = 1.0-(1.0-expy)**effm

  return wk1,wk2,nout,jmax,prob

def getSignificance(wk1, wk2, nout, ofac):
  """ returns the peak false alarm probabilities
  Hence the lower is the probability and the more significant is the peak
  """
  expy = exp(-wk2)          
  effm = 2.0*(nout)/ofac       
  sig = effm*expy
  ind = (sig >  0.01).nonzero()
  sig[ind] = 1.0-(1.0-expy[ind])**effm
  return sig
```

Data,

```
13.5945121951
13.5945121951
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
4.10975609756
4.10975609756
4.10975609756
7.99695121951
7.99695121951
16.237804878
16.237804878
16.237804878
16.0823170732
16.237804878
16.237804878
8.92987804878
8.92987804878
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
28.0548780488
28.0548780488
28.0548780488
27.8993902439
27.8993902439
41.5823170732
41.5823170732
41.5823170732
41.5823170732
41.5823170732
41.5823170732
18.7256097561
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
23.8567073171
23.8567073171
23.8567073171
23.8567073171
25.4115853659
25.4115853659
28.0548780488
40.0274390244
40.0274390244
40.0274390244
40.0274390244
40.0274390244
40.0274390244
20.5914634146
20.5914634146
20.4359756098
19.6585365854
18.2591463415
19.3475609756
18.2591463415
10.3292682927
27.743902439
27.743902439
27.743902439
27.743902439
27.743902439
27.743902439
22.3018292683
22.3018292683
21.368902439
21.368902439
21.368902439
21.5243902439
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
20.4359756098
11.8841463415
11.8841463415
1.0
11.1067073171
10.1737804878
14.5274390244
14.5274390244
14.5274390244
14.5274390244
14.5274390244
14.5274390244
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
12.6615853659
11.7286585366
8.15243902439
1.0
7.84146341463
6.90853658537
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
12.6615853659
13.1280487805
12.9725609756
12.9725609756
12.9725609756
10.3292682927
10.3292682927
10.3292682927
10.3292682927
9.55182926829
10.4847560976
29.9207317073
29.9207317073
29.9207317073
29.9207317073
30.0762195122
30.0762195122
26.1890243902
7.99695121951
25.256097561
7.99695121951
7.99695121951
7.99695121951
6.59756097561
6.59756097561
6.59756097561
6.59756097561
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
10.4847560976
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
16.8597560976
15.9268292683
15.9268292683
16.8597560976
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
9.08536585366
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
6.90853658537
7.84146341463
6.90853658537
4.26524390244
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
14.2164634146
14.2164634146
14.2164634146
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
16.8597560976
16.8597560976
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
17.9481707317
17.9481707317
19.6585365854
19.6585365854
19.6585365854
19.6585365854
10.7957317073
10.7957317073
10.7957317073
10.7957317073
10.7957317073
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
22.9237804878
7.84146341463
7.84146341463
7.84146341463
7.84146341463
8.7743902439
8.7743902439
7.84146341463
8.61890243902
8.61890243902
8.61890243902
8.61890243902
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
18.2591463415
9.39634146341
9.39634146341
9.24085365854
9.24085365854
9.24085365854
9.24085365854
9.08536585366
9.08536585366
9.08536585366
9.08536585366
9.55182926829
9.55182926829
9.55182926829
9.55182926829
9.55182926829
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
16.5487804878
1.0
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
17.1707317073
17.0152439024
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
21.9908536585
7.84146341463
8.7743902439
7.84146341463
6.75304878049
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
3.95426829268
7.06402439024
7.06402439024
7.06402439024
11.262195122
11.262195122
11.262195122
11.262195122
11.262195122
11.262195122
9.08536585366
9.86280487805
7.99695121951
7.99695121951
14.2164634146
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
14.0609756098
2.24390243902
2.08841463415
3.02134146341
3.02134146341
2.08841463415
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.44207317073
6.59756097561
6.59756097561
6.59756097561
6.75304878049
1.0
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
7.21951219512
6.28658536585
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
10.6402439024
14.3719512195
14.3719512195
15.6158536585
15.6158536585
15.6158536585
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
35.6737804878
28.6768292683
28.6768292683
28.6768292683
28.6768292683
28.6768292683
51.8445121951
51.8445121951
51.8445121951
51.8445121951
51.8445121951
52.0
52.0
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
4.10975609756
3.95426829268
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
5.9756097561
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
12.1951219512
1.0
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
11.7286585366
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
11.1067073171
10.0182926829
10.0182926829
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
16.7042682927
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
29.1432926829
1.15548780488
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
3.17682926829
4.10975609756
4.10975609756
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
6.90853658537
5.9756097561
10.1737804878
10.1737804878
10.1737804878
8.61890243902
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
9.39634146341
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
5.35365853659
5.35365853659
5.35365853659
5.35365853659
5.35365853659
5.35365853659
3.33231707317
4.42073170732
3.33231707317
6.59756097561
6.44207317073
5.82012195122
6.75304878049
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
5.82012195122
4.73170731707
5.66463414634
5.66463414634
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
5.66463414634
5.66463414634
5.50914634146
2.71036585366
5.50914634146
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
5.50914634146
5.50914634146
5.50914634146
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
7.06402439024
5.9756097561
7.53048780488
8.46341463415
8.46341463415
13.2835365854
13.2835365854
13.2835365854
13.2835365854
2.55487804878
2.55487804878
2.55487804878
2.55487804878
4.10975609756
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
4.26524390244
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.33231707317
3.33231707317
3.33231707317
2.24390243902
3.33231707317
2.24390243902
2.24390243902
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
7.21951219512
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
3.7987804878
4.73170731707
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
4.26524390244
4.26524390244
5.19817073171
5.19817073171
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
7.53048780488
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
3.95426829268
3.02134146341
3.02134146341
3.02134146341
1.0
1.93292682927
2.55487804878
2.55487804878
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
5.9756097561
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
6.28658536585
16.0823170732
16.0823170732
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
31.3201219512
3.64329268293
3.64329268293
4.26524390244
4.26524390244
3.7987804878
4.73170731707
3.7987804878
3.7987804878
2.55487804878
3.48780487805
2.55487804878
2.55487804878
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
3.33231707317
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
12.3506097561
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
4.73170731707
2.86585365854
2.86585365854
1.46646341463
1.46646341463
1.46646341463
1.46646341463
1.46646341463
1.46646341463
1.62195121951
1.62195121951
1.62195121951
1.77743902439
1.77743902439
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
4.42073170732
3.95426829268
3.95426829268
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
2.71036585366
1.77743902439
2.86585365854
3.02134146341
2.86585365854
2.86585365854
3.17682926829
3.17682926829
```

Plot

[image]

Any help would be appreciated,

Comment: Your **synthetic data are presumably in the time domain** (although they appear  undersampled, so you could possibly benefit from  reading up on the sampling theorem and get some intuition by running some basic FFTs out of `numpy` on your data first).  Your **actual data look already like a spectrum**. I can see clear frequency peaks in them when plotting them. So maybe add some plots to make clearer what you need.

Comment: Hi @roadrunner, the data is in the time domain, not frequency domain, and it  comes from this graph - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Extinction_intensity.svg - I added the plot generated from the data above to the original post.

Comment: Wow. Ty. The shape really threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, it looks like AstroML method is the best.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astroML.time_series import lomb_scargle, search_frequencies
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('extinct.csv',header=None)
Y = df[0]

dy = 0.5 + 0.5 * np.random.random(len(df))
omega = np.linspace(10, 100, 1000)

sig = np.array([0.1, 0.01, 0.001])
PS, z = lomb_scargle(df.index, Y, dy, omega, generalized=True, significance=sig)

plt.plot(omega,PS)
plt.hold(True)

xlim = (omega[0], omega[-1])
for zi, pi in zip(z, sig):
    plt.plot(xlim, (zi, zi), ':k', lw=1)
    plt.text(xlim[-1] - 0.001, zi - 0.02, "$%.1g$" % pi, ha='right', va='top')
    plt.hold(True)
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Significance levels are shown on the graph as well. I used to generalized LS, and used no smoothing.